# Display Objects on FirePHP Logger

Tags: zend-framework2

I just setup FirePHP like this on my getServiceConfig():

```
 use FirePHP as FirePHP;
 use Zend\Log\Logger;
 use Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp as FirePhpWriter;
 use Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp\FirePhpBridge;

'logger_firebug' => function($sm) {

    $log = new Logger();
    $writer = new FirePhpWriter(new FirePhpBridge(new FirePHP()));
    $log->addWriter($writer);
    return $log;
 },
```

but when I try to use the info function on the controller like this:

```
    $loger = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('logger_firebug');     
    $loger->info($this);
```

it gives me an internal error "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"
what I want to do is to display a var_dump of the object.

Can some one help me how to show any object structure?

Thanks

Comment: Anything inside the `error_log`?

Comment: Thank you Sam let me check that.

Comment: Hi Sam this is the message that I am getting "$message must implement magic __toString() method".                               I try doing $this->__toString() but it gets me this message "Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for __toString"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try keeping an instance of `$firephp = new FirePHP()` and using `$firephp->info($this)` to log messages instead.

Comment: Yes!! that worked!! Thank you cardon, Great Job, thank you by the way for making our job easier creating FirePHP, I relay appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

This message tells you exactly what is going on.

`$message must implement magic`[`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionfunction.tostring.php)`method`

Checking the link you'll notice, that [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionfunction.tostring.php) will always, automatically, be called, whenever an `Object` is used in the context of a `String`. So why does this error message occur? Simple: the `$loger->$level()` requires a `String` as an argument, but you are trying to give it an `Object`

How to fix this? Give it a `String`

```
$loger->info(\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($this, $label=null, false));
// Be sure to either set a $label (string) or set it to null
```

Comment: Thanks Sam; It work but how can I set this up so I can see more like structure, like an object with his properties nested or an array with key/value pair nested, what it showing me now is like a whole string with the object info.

Comment: My guess would be that the logger implementation is at fault. No further clues about it :)